# How to get the file in PlayFramework Controller which is sent by angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, playframework

I am currently working on File Upload in PlayFramework with angularJs. When ever i am calling upload function I am receiving 400 bad request response.

Below are my angularJs and Controller code.
Note: I am able to get 200 response from my controller(action) when it has no implementation inside.

```
 $scope.uploadFile = function () {
                $scope.upload($scope.bonus_file, baseURL + 'controller/upload_file');
            };

            // upload on file select or drop
            $scope.upload = function (file, path) {
                alert('Hello');
                Upload.upload({
                    url: path,
                    data: {file: file}
                }).then(function (resp) {
                    if (resp.data.status == 'success') {
                        sweetAlert("Done!", resp.data.message, "success");
                        $scope.bonus_file = '';
                        $scope.salary_file = '';
                    } else {
                        sweetAlert("Oops...", resp.data.message, "error");
                        $scope.bonus_file = '';
                        $scope.salary_file = '';
                    }
                }, function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
                });
            };



public Result uploadFile() {
        play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart picture = body.getFile("file");
        try {
            if (picture != null) {
                String fileName = picture.getFilename();
                String contentType = picture.getContentType();
                java.io.File file = picture.getFile();
                StorageHelper.uploadFile(file, fileName);
                return ok("File uploaded");
            } else {
                return badRequest();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception While Uploading File:" + e.getMessage());
            return ok("File uploaded Failed:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Play's documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaFileUpload#Direct-file-upload):

> Another way to send files to the server is to use Ajax to upload files
>   asynchronously from a form. In this case, the request body will not be
>   encoded as multipart/form-data, but will just contain the plain file
>   contents.

Hence, you should try this:

```
public static play.mvc.Result upload() {
    java.io.File file = request().body().asRaw().asFile();
    return ok("File uploaded");
}
```